# Aspectj @Around annotation, prevents the code called by the method itself to initialize Spring Autowireds

Tags: spring, unit-testing, aspectj, interceptor

I am using an AspectJ interceptor using the @Around annotation to measure specific execution times during **Spring Unit tests**.

When intercepted by Aspectj Aspect @Around annotation,
the code called by the method itself use non initialized Autowired.

The class member annotated with @Value("${some.configured.property}") of at least one autowired Component is not initialized and this lead to a Null Pointer Exception.

The unit test itself works perfectly when not intercepted.

How would you configure Aspectj
to let Spring initialize its Components properly
before interception ?

Comment: I gave up using aspectJ for this task and will use Intellij Profiler integration instead, I will not invest more in this question.